# Load an Office add-in or its add-in command by default

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I take Excel for example. At the moment, every time when a user wants to use an add-in, they need to go to `insert ==> add-ins` and choose the add-in. Then either a take pane or content add-in appears. If the manifest xml of the add-in has [add-in commands](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/add-in-manifests), users can launch the add-in via menu or ribbon.

If the user des-actives the task pane, closes and re-open Excel, they need to go to `insert ==> add-ins` again and so on... It is tedious.

Is it possible to set an add-in loaded by default (either by developers or users)? For example, each time the user opens Excel, they could see the item in the menu or ribbon (or even the task pane activated) to launch the add-in.

Comment: You're asking whether the user can see a ribbon button to launch the add-in whenever they open Excel. But then earlier you also say that you're aware of the add-in commands feature that allows developers to add a ribbon button to do that. So is that a solution to your problem or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the ribbon-button feature mentioned by SoftTimur and Eric is one solution to the problem, another potential solution (depending on your business model) may be to use a template:

You can create a .xlsx document and insert your add-in task pane manually, then share that document with others, who will automatically see the open task pane when they open that document. One strategy is to post this template document online and provide links to it elsewhere.

Comment: I have not implemented the command add-in, so I don't know who (the user or the developper?) sets up the ribbon-button, so that it appears whenever a user open its Excel?

Comment: The developer sets it up and does all the configuration work. All the user needs to do is install that add-in, and from that moment onwards the new ribbon buttons get added for every Excel session and are configured according to the developer.

Comment: And the user needs to configure a little bit to get rid of that ribbon button?

Comment: The user can get rid of it if they want, yes. But by default it always appears once the add-in is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately users have to always manually activate the add-in, either from a Ribbon command or from the Add-ins button.  Only COM add-ins allow you to display a Task Pane when the Office application opens.

Comment: It is fine to manually activate the add-in from a Ribbon command. But how could we let the ribbon command appear by default in the application?

Comment: AFAIK your custom Ribbon commands should appear without having to insert the add-in first.  That's how it works with Outlook add-ins anyway.

Comment: That means, it is the user (rather than the add-in developer) who sets up the Ribbon commands?

Comment: The developer sets up the ribbon commands, but the user lets the developer set it up by enabling (installing) the add-in. Then those ribbon buttons appear every time for each of the user's sessions.